# Merge columns after a certain column number and then drop them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe loaded from a CSV where I have to manually combine Col1, Col2 and Col3. Sometimes I have Cols up to Col8 but it is random with the dataset that I am getting.

Here is what the dataset kinda looks like right now

| Proto | LocalAddress | ForeignAdress | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCP | [0.0.0.0:7] | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING | 4112 | tcpsvcs.exe |
| TCP | 0.0.0.0:111 | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING | 4 | Can not obtain ownership information |

What I am doing right now is manually going through each Col's and combining them into one column like here:

```
ps['Group'] = str(ps['Col6']) + str(ps['Col7']) + str(ps['Col8']) + str(ps['Col9']) + str(ps['Col10'])
```

and then I drop those old columns using `del ps['Col6'], del ps['Col7']`, etc.

I was wondering if there is a way to automate this system? Just combining the columns after a certain number of columns? My dataframe looks great until ForeignAddress but would like to automate the process where we just automatically combine everything after a certain column.

This is what the final dataframe should look like:

| Proto | LocalAddress | ForeignAdress | CombinedCol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCP | [0.0.0.0:7] | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING 4112 tcpsvcs.exe |
| TCP | 0.0.0.0:111 | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING 4 Can not obtain ownership information |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need all columns from `Col6` to last column:

```
df = ps.loc[:, 'Col6':]
ps['Group'] = df.astype(str).agg(' '.join, axis=1)
ps = ps.drop(df.columns, axis=1)
```